# Is there an easy way to use thing-at-point to initialize interactive read string (interactive "sfoo:")

Tags: minibuffer, interactive, read

Is there an easy way to use `thing-at-point` to initialize the contents of an `interactive` string reading?

I have a function the looks something like this:

```lisp
(defun foo (string)
   (interactive "sString:")
   ;; does something with string
   )
```

But I'd really like it if when I did `M-x foo`, that it filled the minibuffer with the `thing-at-point`.  In this case `(thing-at-point 'word)`.

Is the only way to get that to use an explicit list argument to `interactive`, something like:

```
(defun foo (string)
   (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer 
                        "String:" ;; prompt
                        (thing-at-point 'word) ;; initial value
                       ) ) ) ; interactive
   ;; does something with string
   )
```

And if I do so, do my own history list etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `interactive` with a Lisp sexp, not a literal string. You can't specify particular defaulting with a literal string arg.

You can use `read-from-minibuffer`, `read-string`, or `completing-read`.

Provide the value returned by `(thing-at-point 'word)` as the `DEFAULT-VALUE` argument to one of those functions, not the `INITIAL-CONTENTS` argument.

(You can use the initial-contents/input arg if you like, but Emacs convention prefers that you use the default-value arg nowadays.)

As for the input *history* list: you can provide your own history variable, or you can just use the default history list, `minibuffer-history`. If you use your own then the only entries on it will be previous inputs to minibuffer-input reads that use your own history variable. That can mean less noise interactively, but it can also be handy to not be so specific. It's up to you.